# Edit Div when scrolled over (like in google docs)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I want to code something as seen in the Google docs homepage.

When you open it up, it has the template section, then organizing section, etc,
but when you scroll past the organizing section (when, owned by anyone, date, a to z), it manually adds itself to the navbar and adds a box shadow.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAFH7.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6g4W.png)

I've considered using an `eventListener` like:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log("Page is being scrolled")
}
```

But I'm having trouble measuring whether a user has scrolled a specific amount of pixels through the page. Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd simply add a listener for when the user is scrolling, then if the user has scrolled a set amount of pixels do something.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log("scrolled")
}
```

Now when scrolling the text "scrolling" will be logged in the console. So now we need to add an if statement, checking if you've scrolled to a certain amount down the page, this is calculated in pixels.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 {
        console.log("User Scrolled past 50pixels
    }
}
```

Now when you've scrolled 50px down the page the console will log it. So you'd just have to change the css code of the navbar to have a fixed position at the top, as soon as you've scrolled down to it, and when you scroll above 50px remove that CSS.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 {
        // Make the div fixed here
    } else {
        // Remove the css making the div fixed
    }
}
```

Of course the 50 can be changed to any number you prefer.
For example on Google Docs, it makes the nav fixed when you've scrolled about 205px down...

**Hope this helps!**